# jest.mock how to find whether the mocked function was called or not

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I m mocking a module like this:

```
jest.mock('@/src/myModule.ts', () => ({
  load: jest.fn(),
  delete: jest.fn(),
}));
```

In my test how I can check whether load was called or not?

```
it('some test', () => {
  const x = someFunction(); // this method is calling myModule.ts/load
  expect(???);
});
```

The point is I cannot reference load from outside, so if I try this

```
const objs = {
    load: jest.fn(),
    delete: jest.fn(),
};
jest.mock('@/src/myModule.ts', () => objs);
```

and then try to refer 'objs', its not working

```
...
expect(objs.load).toBeCalledTimes(1); // failed
...
```

Comment: There are various options in the docs, the simplest is to use the matchers: https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#custom-matchers

Comment: @jonrsharpe did u read my question?

Comment: Yes. If that's not what you're asking please [edit] to clarify which specific part of that you _are_ having trouble with. Give a [mre].

Comment: Could you expand on `failed` - called no times, presumably? What _is_ `someFunction`? You could also `import { load } from "..."` to get access to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
const loadMock = jest.fn()
jest.mock('@/src/myModule.ts', () => ({
  load: () => loadMock(),
  delete: jest.fn(),
}));
```

In your test you can check whether load was called or not:

```
it('some test', () => {
  const x = someFunction(); // this method is calling myModule.ts/load
  expect(loadMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: No it does't work, it works if load: () => loadMock()